# Configure HADOOP job with Javaconfig

Tags: spring, hadoop

I am following now the introduction page of Spring HADOOP at http://blog.springsource.org/2012/02/29/introducing-spring-hadoop/

The example configurations are xml based. The following code describes the wordCount example.

```
<!-- define the job -->
<hdp:job id="word-count"
  input-path="/input/" output-path="/ouput/"
  mapper="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.TokenizerMapper"
  reducer="org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.IntSumReducer"/>

<!-- execute the job -->
<bean id="runner" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.JobRunner"
              p:jobs-ref="word-count"/>
```

Is there a way to configure this example with Javaconfig?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set hadoop configuration programmatically by using the [`Configuration`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) object's various `.set()` methods, like so:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("example.foo", "bar");
```

Comment: This makes the solution less springy. I meant a javaconfig solution with annotations, like the following post http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-javaconfig-example/

Comment: As far as I am aware an annotation based configuration system does not exist, this is the only solution I know of from within java itself. If you prefer you could set them on the command line with `-Dexample.foo=bar` though when starting your hadoop job.

Comment: The current release of 'Spring for Hadoop' 1.0 doesn't support annotation for Hadoop components yet. As of this release, only way to configure is using the .xml files

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableHadoop
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:config/hadoop.properties"})
public class HadoopConfiguration extends SpringHadoopConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(HadoopConfigConfigurer config) throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    config.fileSystemUri("hdfs://");
    config.withProperties(props).property("propkey", "propvalue").and();
}
}
```